# True or False: If $S_1$ ∩ $S_2$ ≠ 0, then Span($S_1$ ∩ $S_2$) ⊆ Span($S_1$) ∩ Span($S_2$)

Tags: linear-algebra

If $S_1$ ∩ $S_2$ ≠ 0, then Span($S_1$ ∩ $S_2$) ⊆ Span($S_1$) ∩ Span($S_2$)

I know the answer is false but I am having trouble coming up with an example showing why it is false.

Comment: Since $A\subseteq B$ implies $span(A) \subseteq span(B)$, I think the statement is true even without the condition $S_1 \cap S_2 \ne \{0\}$.

Answer (score 2):

If $S_1$ and $S_2$ are subsets of a vector space, then

Span($S_1$ ∩ $S_2$) ⊆ Span($S_1$) ∩ Span($S_2$)

is true !

We have $S_1 \cap S_2\subseteq S_1$, thus  span($S_1 \cap S_2)\subseteq span(S_1$).

The same reasons give span($S_1 \cap S_2)\subseteq span(S_2$).